# How to make a User Control that behaves like a combobox but with an editable textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to make a Searchbox, so i want to create a User Control, that display a textbox but when typed on will call a dropdown list similar to that of a combobox. ¿is this posible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the input that you are describing called AutoComplete, 
and WPFToolkit suggest easy to use one
https://github.com/dotnetprojects/WpfToolkit

Comment: Thanks! This helped me a lot!